# Не работает контекстное меню

Tags: c++, qt

У меня есть в форме listWidget.
В конструкторе окна я привязываю customContextMenuRequested к моей функции ShowContextMenu:

```
connect(ui->list, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),this,SLOT(ShowContextMenu(QPoint)));
```

Но при нажатии ПКМ на виджет ничего не происходит.
(даже функция не вызывается)

Answer (score 0):

Этот сигнал эмитируется, когда установлено значение политики контекстного меню Qt::CustomContextMenu . 
А значением по умолчанию является Qt::DefaultContextMenu. 
Ситуацию исправило:

```
ui->list->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
```